# Microsoft word: Text outside page border

Tags: microsoft-word

My sister has a word 2010 document and the text is very much outside the right page border. This doesn't happen on the first 3 pages, but does occur on all other pages.

I tried to create smaller right margins, move the ruler to the left, use different standard margin profiles, but nothing seems to work. How can we solve this?

Here's an example of the document:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, I added the image for you.

Comment: Was the text copied from a website? Maybe it's inside a table. If that's so, try copying only the text and pasting it outside the table, and see if it gets wrapped properly.

Comment: You sir, are awesome! The tekst was indeed inside an invisble table. Removing the table and pasting the tekst back in the document solved the problem ;) Thank you very much!

Comment: @Forza: Glad it worked! Am posting the comment as an answer so you can mark this thread as being resolved if you wish. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the text was copied from a website, maybe it's inside a table. If that's so, try copying only the text and pasting it outside the table, and see if it gets wrapped properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you copy the entire contents of your document, then "Paste Special" that will clear any and all formatting that is currently on the text.  If this fixes it then it is a page/paragraph/etc formatting problem.  Which is probably the case, it's just hard sometimes to find what or where the formatting issue is at.

On the ribbon is the "Paste" button, if you click the down arrow the "Paste Special" option is there.  From the paste special window you want to use the "Unformatted text" option.

Comment: Also a nice trick I didn't knew yet ;) Thank you!

Comment: Especially if you are copy and pasting from a website it always will clear whatever formatting is being copied from the website.

Answer (score 0):

Some other solutions for this issue:

1. If your only goal is to be able to read all the text including the text that is running off the page, then go to **VIEW**…then choose “**Full Screen Reading**” mode.
2. But if your goal is to fix this formatting problem within MS Word, then select the text you want to fix, and use the "convert to text" button.  You'll find this button under "**Table Tools**" then under "**Layout**." But, the Table Tools menu will NOT appear on your menu bar unless you've properly select the table first.  Your messed up lines are sitting inside a table which you can't see.

   3. Another option to fix the issue is to again click on / select the invisible table in which your text sits...then choose "**AutoFit**" then “**AutoFit Window**.”  Again, you won't see an Autofit menu option unless the Table Tools menu comes up, which only happens when you select the table.

This happens to me sometimes when I copy and paste email contents **from** **Gmail** into a Microsoft Word document. All the column/table formatting is coming along for the ride.  You can avoid the problem entirely by being careful how you choose to paste the text into Word. Don't go with the default.  **Choose a Paste Option that doesn't retain the source formatting**.

Comment: You can resize the table

Answer (score 0):

Try to select the table and then check Table Properties and set the "preferred width" to 7.5" or whatever size will fit with your margins.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what solved the problem in my case: for reasons of its own, Word had formatted the entire text as a two-column layout. Resetting it to single-column layout fixed the problem of text running over the page border.

Here's how to do it: click on **Layout > Columns > One** (that's on Word for Mac, it'll be similar in other versions).